# Find items and expire given partial key in ehcache

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache

I have a need to expire certain items cached with ehcache manually, but not sure if I can identify them.

For example, I have a method signature like the following,

```
@Cacheable(value = XHTML_CACHE_NAME)
public Map<String, Object> build(String documentName, 
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    ResponseEntity<String> entity = getRestResponse(documentName, authorities);
    if (entity != null) {
        DocumentEntity documentEntity = new DocumentEntity
                .Builder(entity.getBody()).build();
        String html = (documentEntity.getBody() != null) ? 
                documentEntity.getBody() : entity.getBody();

        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("html", html);

        response.put("documentEntity", documentEntity);
        return response;
    } else {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }
}
```

For my particular use case, I know the `name` at the time I need to expire the cache, but not the `groups`.

Would anyone know if it's possible to find all items in the cache with a particular `name` without knowledge of the `groups`? I'm using Spring 3.2.4 and ehcache 2.6.6.

Thanks, /w

Comment: The method returns a Map with a String key. Does this key correspond to the `name`?

Comment: No it doesn't @WillKeeling. The returned string is an xhtml document, and `name` is the name of that document.

Comment: So the Map is a map of xhtml documents keyed by name?

Comment: The reason I ask is that ehcache exposes a query API which can select back specific items from the cache in an efficient way. It may be possible to utilize this API to achieve what you want.

Comment: @WillKeeling I added the rest of the `build` method for clarity. The key of the map is the body of an xhtml document, and the value is an object mostly containing metadata and related information about the document.